# iOS Mail app - font-family is always Times New Roman with my template

Tags: ios, fonts, outlook

So I can see the needed result on GoDaddy and on Gmail but iOS Mail App keeps showing a plain Times New Roman with no margins/align. Just plain text shown on a Times New Roman font.
I can't really understand why that happens since my "fallback" fonts are Helvetica and Arial and I receive dozens of HTML emails daily with different fonts and even images and it all looks cool for them..

```
<!--[if mso]>
<center>
<table><tr><td width="580">
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">

/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/0eC6fl06luXEYWpBSJvXCBJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Fl4y0QdOxyyTHEGMXX8kcRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/-L14Jk06m6pUHB-5mXQQnRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/I3S1wsgSg9YCurV6PUkTORJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/NYDWBdD4gIq26G5XYbHsFBJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Pru33qjShpZSmG3z6VYwnRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
</style>


<div style="max-width:580px; margin:0 auto; font-size: 18.5px;">

<span style="font-family: 'Roboto Light', Helvetica, Arial; font-weight: 300;">Some text
</span>

 </div>
<!--[if mso]>
 </td></tr></table>
 </center>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Are these typist double quotes in your original source, or is this a copy-paste thing? `<style type=”text/css”>`

Comment: God... have no idea how it got there. Anyway I've edited that to `<style type="text/css">` and it still doesn't show up properly on iOS Mail.